# How to patch property of list in nested object with condition for restful api

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, patch, api-design

How should i design a Restful API for PATCH operation that support update some property in the a list with condition?

say i have following json model:

```
{
"key1": "value",
"key2": "value",
"list": [
    {
        "property": "someValue",
        "toBePatched": "value"
    },
    {
        "property": "otherValue",
        "toBePatched": "value"
    }
]
```

}

I need to patch the "toBePatched" property in the list when the "property" equals to "someValue". By looking at the json patch [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), i think it is a good way to go, but i dont think the json pointer supports the query? how should i define a path that supports "/list/property=someValue/toBePatch"?

One stupid way to do it is to pass it as query parameter to the api, and have some logic around it, but i dont think thats a standard way to do it.

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't have the answer for `application/patch+json`, but you can also make your own patch format, if you find that application/patch+json is too convoluted for your use-case or can't express the exact change you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  { "op": "test", "path": "/list/0/property", "value": "someValue"},
  { "op": "test", "path": "/list/0/toBePatched", "value": "value"},
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/list/0/toBePatched", "value": "the-new-value"}
]
```

[test](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6) is important, it lets you verify that the server hasn't change the part of the document that you are intending to change.  See section 5 on [Error Handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-5) for details.